# How to match 2 lines of html code in a index.html file using egrep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

i m try to `grep` two lines of `html` pattern from a file and print using `cat`. The lines are:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://test.mydomain.com/store.css">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://test.mydomain.com/store/gwt.nocache.js">
```

if i use them seperatly using `grep` command. like

```
if grep -F -i -n '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://test.mydomain.com/store.css">' tmp.html > out.txt; then cat out.txt # IT WORKS.
```

but i am in need to `grep` both the pattern. i tried with `egrep`. as

```
egrep '(pattern1|pattern2)'
```

as

```
if egrep -e -i -c '(\<link type\=\"text\/css\" rel\=\"stylesheet\" href\=\"https\:\//test\.mydomain\.com\/gwtstore\/store\.css\"\>|\<link type\=\"text\/css\" rel\=\"stylesheet\" href\=\"https\:\//test\.mydomain\.com\/store\/gwt\.nocache\.js\"\>)' tmp.html > out.txt; then cat out.txt
```

but the above syntax not working out.. please Assist. all i m try to search two set of html code in a file, if they exit replace with another pattern using `sed` command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: If you want to work with sed on it, you can do it immediately with sed - why do you want to use grep too?

Answer (score 0):

Use fgrep with -e option like this

```
fgrep -e 'firts_pattern' -e 'second_pattern'
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  but how to display line no.  i used -n flag but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use sed you may just want to use the following. You may not need two separate commands. Using sed you can find if the two patterns exist and if so replace both of them with one command.

NOTE: The following contains an inline edit. PLEASE BACKUP YOUR FILE PRIOR TO TESTING

```
sed -i 's/<link type="text\/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https:\/\/test.mydomain.com\/store.css">/<REPLACE PATTERN 1>/g;s/<script type="text\/javascript" language="javascript" src="https:\/\/test.mydomain.com\/store\/gwt.nocache.js">/<REPLACE PATTERN 2>/g' /yourfile
```

If you are an OS X user you can try the following

NOTE: The following contains an inline edit. PLEASE BACKUP YOUR FILE PRIOR TO TESTING

```
sed -i '' 's/<link type="text\/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https:\/\/test.mydomain.com\/store.css">/<REPLACE PATTERN 1>/g;s/<script type="text\/javascript" language="javascript" src="https:\/\/test.mydomain.com\/store\/gwt.nocache.js">/<REPLACE PATTERN 2>/g' /yourfile
```

Remember to escape the '/' characters in your REPLACE PATTERN if you intend on using them.

Also you may want to try awk. In this case it functions much like grep.

```
awk '/<link type="text\/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https:\/\/test.mydomain.com\/store.css">/; /<script type="text\/javascript" language="javascript" src="https:\/\/test.mydomain.com\/store\/gwt.nocache.js">/' /yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

with egrep you don't need those parenthesis, just the pipe separating the patterns inside single quotes.

`egrep -n 'pattern1|pattern2'`

should work just fine.